# How to loop through a string for a regex match, concat return new full string

Tags: javascript, regex, dictionary, match

I'm trying to achieve:

```
const finalStr = "team='Core', team='Mechanics'"
//loop through string, get single quotes, add <bold>'Core'</bold>
//I want to return the string: 
"team=<bold>'Core'</bold>, team=<bold>'Mechanics'</bold>"
```

What I've tried, but obviously wrong...can't wrap my head around it:

```
const finalStr = this.state.finalString
const newFinal = finalStr.match(/'(.*?)'/g).map(item => {
    item = item.replace(item, '<b>' + item + '</b>')
      return item;
    });
```

Comment: no need to loop, just `replace` once: `replace(/.../g, '<b>$&</b>')`

Comment: Are you trying to generate HTML with that? If so, the correct tag is `<b>`, not `<bold>`, as that tag doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks @georg Perfect!  I over-complicated it as usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a callback or any additional functions, just use the `replacement pattern` described in the [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) documentation to insert the matched substring (`$&`). You also don't need the parenthesis for the capture group unless you're intending to do something else with the matches.

```js
const finalStr = "team='Core', team='Mechanics'"

const newFinal = finalStr.replace(/'.*?'/g, '<bold>$&</bold>')
console.log(newFinal)
```

As a side note, there is no `<bold>` tag in HTML, so if you are trying to create valid HTML you should be using `<b>`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the same basic regular expression, `/'.*?'/gi`, with a custom "replacer" callback passed to the `string#replace` method to solve this:

```js
const input = "team='Core', team='Mechanics'"

const output = input.replace(/'.*?'/gi, function(matchStr) {

  // Wrap each match in the resulting string with <bold /> tags 
  return '<bold>' + matchStr + '</bold>';
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: The regular expression in the original attempt would capture multi-word items, but using `\w` prevents this, so it won't produce exactly the same results. OP didn't specify that as a requirement, but it might be good to note.

Comment: @Herohtar thanks for the feedback - very good point, I'd only paid attention to the input data in the OP and hadn't considered that possibility of white-spaces etc. Thanks again!